# expresion regular solo letras y espacios html

Tags: html

Como puedo contruir una expresión regular que solo contenga espacios y letras ASCII normales quiero decir

```html
<form action="resultado.php" method="post">
            <select name="cifrado">
    
                <option value="cifrar">Cifrar</option>
    
                <option value="descifrar">Descifrar</option>
    
            </select>   
    
    </select><br/>
               <!–  Introducimos el texto a cifrar/descrifrar ->
                
                <label for="texto">Texto a descrifrar o descifrar</label>
                <input type="text" name="texto" pattern="[A-Za-z ]><br />
    
                <label for="desplazamiento">desplazamiento</label>
                <input type="number" name="desplazamiento"><br />
    
    
                <!–  Borrar los valores ->
                <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>    
                <input type="reset" value="Borrar">
    
                <!–  Recoger los datos ->
                <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
                <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
    
            </form>
```

pongo este pattern pero no funciona

```
pattern="[A-Za-z]{2-254}"
```

**resultado.php**

```
    <?php
function encrypt($str, $offset) {
    $encrypted_text = "";
    $offset = $offset % 26;
    if($offset < 0) {
        $offset += 26;
    }
    $i = 0;
    // mientras la longitud sea menos de $str
    while($i < strlen($str)) {
        //Convierte str a mayusculas
        $c = strtoupper($str{$i}); 
        if(($c >= "A") && ($c <= 'Z')) {
            //devuelve el valor ASCII de un caracter
            if((ord($c) + $offset) > ord("Z")) {
                //ASCII y devuelve un caracter especifico
                $encrypted_text .= chr(ord($c) + $offset - 26);
        } else {
            $encrypted_text .= chr(ord($c) + $offset);
        }
      } else {
          $encrypted_text .= " ";
      }
      $i++;
    }
    return $encrypted_text;
}
function decrypt($str, $offset) {
    $decrypted_text = "";
    $offset = $offset % 26;
    if($offset < 0) {
        $offset += 26;
    }
    $i = 0;
    while($i < strlen($str)) {
        $c = strtoupper($str{$i}); 
        if(($c >= "A") && ($c <= 'Z')) {
            if((ord($c) - $offset) < ord("A")) {
                $decrypted_text .= chr(ord($c) - $offset + 26);
        } else {
            $decrypted_text .= chr(ord($c) - $offset);
        }
      } else {
          $decrypted_text .= " ";
      }
      $i++;
    }
    return $decrypted_text;
}

//sample text

if ($_POST["texto"] != ""&& $_POST["cifrado"] != ""
    && $_POST["desplazamiento"] != "" ) {

        $text = $_POST["texto"];
        $offset = $_POST["desplazamiento"] ;
        $enc = $_POST["cifrado"];
    if ($enc == "cifrar") {

        $result=encrypt($text, $offset);

    } elseif ($_POST["cifrado"] == "descifrar") {

        $result=decrypt($text, $offset);
    }

    echo $result;

    print ('<br /><a href="cesar.php">Volver</a> ');

    }else{
        print ("Introduzca un texto válido");

        print ('<br /><a href="cesar.php">Volver</a>');
    } 







?>
```

Comment: Utiliza `pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s]{2,254}"` y cuando presiones el boton `Enviar` debe de mostrarte una alerta. Si necesitas validar por cada caracter ingresado, entonces utiliza el evento `keyUp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
 pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{2,254}"
```

Te permitirá ingresar letras de la hasta  la z, un con un mínimo de 2 caracteres y máximo 254

Comment: pattern="[A-Za-z ]" así sería? si es así no me deja poner asd ni a a a

Comment: si prueba con eso, ya que hay un espacio al final

Comment: no me deja poner hola mundo

Comment: edite la respuesta lo he probado y funciona segun el requerimiento

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la respuesta del usuario @Igmer-Rodriguez, funciona correctamente, puedes ejecutar el siguiente snippet y deja escribir perfectamente hola mundo, y no deja pasar caracteres especiales:

```html
<form action="resultado.php" method="post">
            <select name="cifrado">
    
                <option value="cifrar">Cifrar</option>
    
                <option value="descifrar">Descifrar</option>
    
            </select>   
    
    </select><br/>
               <!–  Introducimos el texto a cifrar/descrifrar ->
                
                <label for="texto">Texto a descrifrar o descifrar</label>
                <input type="text" name="texto" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{2,254}"><br />
    
                <label for="desplazamiento">desplazamiento</label>
                <input type="number" name="desplazamiento"><br />
    
    
                <!–  Borrar los valores ->
                <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>    
                <input type="reset" value="Borrar">
    
                <!–  Recoger los datos ->
                <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
                <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
    
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

el pattern que buscas puede ser el siguiente

`pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s]+{2,254}"`

Pero debes tener en cuenta que este atributo no evita que puedas agregar números en el campo, sólo funciona de tal manera que al presionar un botón submit de un formulario, el campo debe cumplir con la expresión regular de manera correcta, si no los datos del form no pueden ser enviados.

Comment: no me funciona, pongo numeros y me los lanza, amplio todo el code que tengo

Comment: Recuerda que para que funcione el **input** debe estar dentro de un form que tenga un ya sea un input del tipo submit o un botón del mismo tipo, a lo mejor si agregas más piezas de código pueda saber porque no funciona